# How to Measure many voltages (Uno) - Analog extenders a good option?

Tags: arduino-uno, battery, voltage, analog

**I am trying to make a battery capacity tester** (3.7v li-ion 18650 battery) using arduino uno. If possible i'd like to test 20 or more batteries at the same time. **I need to measure the voltage of each battery every 1 second.**

The uno has 6 anolog inputs iirc so too little for this application. 
**I think using analog multiple extenders (connected using I2C) chained together to create enough analog inputs.**
**For example this one**: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32858973834.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.57206143DNgWKp&algo_pvid=526d42f2-f7ee-4781-932b-947744ac631e&algo_expid=526d42f2-f7ee-4781-932b-947744ac631e-0&btsid=89c452fa-1d7c-4ae9-9dd5-ed8fc9bff128&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_8,searchweb201603_52
**Do you think I'll be able to get relatively accurate voltage measurements using this approach?**

The purpose of the circuit is to measure the amount of mah (battery capacity) of the 18650 battery which is being discharged via the 10Ohm resistor. The battery will be discharged from 4.2volt (fully charged) to approx 2.5V using the 10ohm resistor, each second the voltage drop over the resistor will be measured and using it and the time passed the integral of time*current will be calculated to determine the capacity.

**This is the basic circuit used to connect each 18650 battery**, the ANALOG1 pin will be connected to the input of the analog extenders:
[image]
(I based it off of the circuit from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WScPyfQz_f8)
The idea is to measure the voltage drop over the 10Ohm10W power resistor and calculate the current using the known resistance value, calculate the integral of current*time to get a capacity value for the battery.

**Is this a good approach? Would you recommend using analog extenders for this? If not what would be a better solution? Thank you very much!**

Comment: @jsotola My mistake I don't indeed, only need 1, will edit post

Comment: I'd go for a set of 8-input ADCs, such as https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MCP3208-BI-P/MCP3208-BI-P-ND/319443  8 channels, 12-bit resolution, fast SPI access.  That 10 ohm resistor may get pretty warm. How will you disconnect the battery when it gets low on charge so that it doesn't become damaged from over-discharge?

Comment: Your circuit will draw about 360 mA from each battery through your 10 Ω resistor. Do you have a way to disconnect the batteries when they are not being tested?

Comment: @Duncan C For disconnecting the battery i will use a mosfet which i will turn off using arduino when battery voltage gets too low. I forgot to draw it in the circuit

Comment: @Crossroads thank you for the suggestion i will look inyo using that approach. The battery will be disconnected using a mosfet which is controlled by arduino which turns off the mosfet when the battery voltage gets too low

Comment: I personally made good experience with using analog multiplexers (that's the same thing that the arduino does to provide 8 analog inputs while only having 1 ADC, but of course CrossRoad's approach is fine, too. The circuit you provided doesn't work, you measure the battery's voltage directly which potentially can destroy the arduino. Take a look at the circuit shown in the video again. you need 2 analog inputs to measure the voltage drop over the shunt (current) and at least a voltage divider to measure the voltage

Comment: So you're going to have a 10 Ω power resistor wired into your circuit at all times? That means you'll be draining almost .4 A of current from your battery at all times. If it's a 4 Ah battery, your measurement resistor will drain your battery in 10 hours, with no actual load. Seems to me that you should have the MOSFET off by default, turn it on for an instant, measure the input into your analog pin, then turn the MOSFET back off.

Comment: @ Duncan C Thank you for your concern. I have not explained the purpose of the circuit properly, sorry. The purpose of the circuit is to measure the amount of mah (battery capacity) of the 18650 battery which is being discharged via the 10Ohm resistor. The battery will be discharged from 4.2volt (fully charged) to approx 2.5V using the 10ohm resistor, each second the voltage drop over the resistor will be measured and using it and the time passed the integral of time*current will be calculated to determine the capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is two separate questions and I answer your first question of reading multiple analog values using one ADC and the answer is Yes you can use this approach but  you should give enough time for each channel to charge internal ADC capacitor when you change channel .so if you use more independent ADC you get more time for each channel and result is better